# ip_tables does not get included in kernel modules

Tags: yocto, iptables, kernel-module, imx6

I am trying to add iptables to my imx6ullevk image but kernel modules do not get included.

Added to build/conf/local.conf;

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += " kernel-modules"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " iptables "
IMAGE_FSTYPES += "tar.bz2"
```

After setting new kernel configuration with menuconfig i can see the new configurations in the .config file. I have created a bsp layer with a defconfig using it.

```
> CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
> CONFIG_NF_TABLES=y
> CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y
> CONFIG_NFT_REJECT=y
...
```

After the build i can't find "net" kernel modules in the image files: /lib/modules/4.9.11.../kernel/net/ folder is empty. So iptables is in the image but ip_tables kernel modules are not.
**After changing the machine to qemux86 modules get included.**

When i test the image on the device i see that iptables is looking for modules under a different kernel version. Just to test if the modules are included in the original version i copy the kernel modules to the required version and test again.

```
root@imx6ullevk:~# iptables -L
modprobe: can't change directory to '4.9.88+g5e23f9d61147': No such file or directory
iptables v1.8.3 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.


root@imx6ullevk:/lib/modules# ls -l
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          1040 Jan  1  1970 4.14.98-imx+g1175b59

#Copy kernel just to see if they are included
root@imx6ullevk:/lib/modules# cp -r 4.14.98-imx+g1175b59 4.9.88+g5e23f9d61147
root@imx6ullevk:/lib/modules# ls -l
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          1040 Jan  1  1970 4.14.98-imx+g1175b59
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          1040 Dec  8 13:11 4.9.88+g5e23f9d61147
root@imx6ullevk:/lib/modules# iptables -L
modprobe: module ip_tables not found in modules.dep
iptables v1.8.3 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

I am using https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform repo for yocto and i have tried zeus, rocko and dunfell branches.

What could be the problem? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You're not building net support as modules, the support is built-in the kernel. So... well. It works, not the way you intended it to. Please explain the actual issue (if it's missing kernel modules, the support is just built-in with above code, so it's not the issue).

Comment: I have added command outputs. Is there anything else i could check?

Comment: Have you run menuconfig again after adding the defconfig to your layer? That's one way to make sure that your defconfig is actually used and not something else. You might want to check also that you enabled enough options with menuconfig. Quick google gives this (up-to-date?) website: https://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x651.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.